# javaemvreader android example code

Tags: smartcard, emv

I am trying to build an android application to read credit card / Smart card data form a Micro USB Smart Card reader.
When I use this app from google play, it can read all card data successfully using my card reader:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scdroid.emvdemo&hl=en

According to developer's website they use this library to build this app:
https://code.google.com/p/javaemvreader/

Unfortunately I tried to use the code in it but I am getting Terminal Exception :

> sasc.terminal.TerminalException: No provider available

My Code looks like this:

```js
    protected void testSCReader() {
       SmartCard smartCard = null;
       CardConnection conn = null;

       try {
            conn = TerminalUtil.connect(TerminalUtil.State.CARD_PRESENT);
            if(conn == null){
               rawT.append("TerminalUtil.connect returned null");
               return;
            }
   
            SessionProcessingEnv env = new SessionProcessingEnv();
            env.setReadMasterFile(true);
            env.setProbeAllKnownAIDs(true);
            CardSession cardSession = CardSession.createSession(conn, env);

            smartCard = cardSession.initCard();

            EMVSession session = EMVSession.startSession(smartCard, conn);
            session.initContext();

            for (EMVApplication app : smartCard.getEmvApplications()) {
                    session.selectApplication(app);
                    session.initiateApplicationProcessing(); //GET PROCESSING OPTIONS + READ  RECORD(s)
                    if (!app.isInitializedOnICC()) {
                        //Skip if GPO failed (might not be a EMV card, or conditions not satisfied)
                        continue;
                    }

                    //Be VERY CAREFUL when setting this, as it WILL block the application if the PIN Try Counter reaches 0
                    //Must be combined with a PIN callback handler
                    EMVTerminal.setDoVerifyPinIfRequired(false);
                    session.prepareTransactionProcessing();
        
                    //Check if the transaction processing skipped some steps

                    if(app.getATC() == -1 || app.getLastOnlineATC() == -1) {
                        session.testReadATCData(); //ATC, Last Online ATC
                    }

                    //If PIN Try Counter has not been read, try to read it
                    if(app.getPINTryCounter() == -1) {
                        session.readPINTryCounter();
                    }

                    if(!app.isTransactionLogProcessed()) {
                        session.checkForTransactionLogRecords();
                    }
                   

                    //testGetChallenge (see if the app supports generating an unpredictable number)

                    session.testGetChallenge();

            }

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Finished Processing card.");
            System.out.println("Now dumping card data in a more readable form:");
            System.out.println("\n");
 

            rawT.append("Finished Processing card.");

            //See the finally clause

        } catch (TerminalException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            rawT.append(ex.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedCardException ex) {
            System.err.println("Unsupported card: " + ex.getMessage());
            rawT.append(ex.toString());
            if (conn != null) {
                //System.err.println("ATR: " + Util.prettyPrintHexNoWrap(conn.getATR()));
                System.err.println(ATR_DB.searchATR(conn.getATR()));
            }
        } catch (SmartCardException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            rawT.append(ex.toString());
        } finally {
            if (conn != null){
                try{
                    conn.disconnect(true);
                }catch(TerminalException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
            if (smartCard != null) {
                try {
                  /* int indent = 0;
                    Log.d("FHD_DBG","======================================");
                    Log.d("FHD_DBG","             [Smart Card]             ");
                    Log.d("FHD_DBG","======================================");
                    smartCard.dump(Log.d, indent);
                    Log.d("FHD_DBG","---------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("FHD_DBG","                FINISHED               ");
                    Log.d("FHD_DBG","---------------------------------------");
                    //Log.getPrintWriter().flush();*/
                rawT.append(smartCard.toString());
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
                Log.d("FHD_DBG","");
            } else if (conn != null) {
            rawT.append(new sasc.iso7816.ATR(conn.getATR()).toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Actually today I found that the main issue is that for some reason it is not able to find a class in javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory library due to which there was a ClassNotFound Exception.
Strange thing is, I did include JDK1.7 library which has javax.smartcardio library, but it still is not visible to compiler???
Can someone explain please?

Comment: any luck with this??

Answer (score 0):

I received the same problem, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory. 
This is because javax.smartcardio.* is not available in the java environment which comes with the android java compiler, its available in JRE.

Comment: I found https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sasc.android.smartcard&hl=ru app wich use exactly this library inside plus some classes which is not available in repository. And it works on Nexus 5 (6.0.1) + USB OTG reader.